# Installing and configuring a barebones email server on Ubuntu

Tags: email, ubuntu, webserver

I've got an unmanaged Linux VPS running ubuntu that I'm using for the web server for a personal website.  I'd like to get a barebones email server up and running.  All the installation guides I've found so far are for a full-fledged email server with a webmail interface and everything.  That's a lot more than I need.  There's only two things I need:

- My web application needs to be able to send email.  Specifically, it'll be emailing me when an exception occurs.
- I want all email sent to [anything]@domain.com forwarded to my personal gmail account.  The server doesn't even need to retain the email or anything.

I want to reserve resources for the actual web app, so I don't want to install anything I won't need for this.

Answer (score 1):

[msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) or [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) sounds like it would fit the bill for the former. You could use google mail for domains for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Your web application needs a SMTP server.  That server can be a hosted service like Google's or [MailHop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto).  If you really want to be an email administrator postfix should be installed [HOWTO is here](http://www.dyndns.com/services/mailhop/).

If not:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll Second Postfix.  I've been using it since around 2000 - it's not that hard to set up.  However, for what you're doing (relaying to your ISP) msmtp or nullmailer as suggested by geocar will probably do the trick - they appear to be specifically designed for this sort of role - although I've never used them so I can't really comment from experience in the way I can with Postfix.